# Converting many variables from long to wide in R

Tags: r, reshape2

I wish to convert many variables from long to wide in R. I have clustered data with family as a cluster, and in each family individuals. For each individual several measured variables, each measured more than once. In the example below, you can see two variables x and y, each measured twice.

I know how to do this for one variable, using the reshape2 package and the dcast function, but it doesn't work for more than one.

I am attaching a picture of example data and the code that generated it.

```
family = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
id = c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
time = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
x = round(runif(18,1,10))
y = round(runif(18,1,10))

D = data.frame(family, id, time, x, y)
```

[image]

The output should be a data frame with the following variables: family, id, x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2.

Edit:

You can see an example here:

[image]

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a unique identifier row for every `family`, `id` and `time` variable and then use `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)

D %>% 
   group_by(family, id, time) %>% 
   mutate(row = row_number()) %>% 
   tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(x, y))
```

Comment: Your code has created two rows for every id, if I am not mistaken. I am no expert of pipes, but does your code created a unique id, or is this my mistake ?

Comment: @user2899944 Can you update your post with expected output for the given example?

Comment: Yes of course, thanks !

Comment: From where do you get 3 and 1 in `y_1` and `y_2` for 1st row? Are those random numbers? Can you add exact expected output atleast for first few rows? Also always use `set.seed` for generation of random numbers so that we can reproduce the same numbers at our end.

Comment: You are correct, I re-ran the code and got different numbers...I'll fix it now

Comment: @user2899944 Please try `D %>%
  group_by(family, id, time) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = time, values_from = c(x, y)) `

Comment: Seems to be working, thanks ! Maybe you can change the main response so I can mark it as solved and thank you appropriately. :-)